# HTML Canvas and/or SVG draws green in Chrome, expected in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, svg

I decided to play around with `Canvas` and SVG this morning so I could learn about these elements more. So I came up with an idea to copy an image from a canvas element and convert it to a bunch of SVG rects.

It was pretty simple but I found a strange bug in Chrome: most of rects are colored green!

Here is a sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iKvBe

Look at it in Chrome and Firefox. Any idea what is going on?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on occasion.  But it is clearly a JS/V8 optimisation bug.  You should report it as a Chrome bug.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list